# Adding a UILabel on a UIImageView inside a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel

All the similar questions on SO and on the net are regarding placing a UILabel on a UIImageView, which is something i am familiar with, however i have to place multiple UILabel's on multiple UIImageView's. One on each UIImageView. I have a for loop like this:

```
    for(int i=0;i < [arrURL count] ;i++)
    {
        UIImageView *view_Image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 400, 180)];
        y = y + 182;

        view_Image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:arrURL[i]]]];


        UILabel  *lblName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(view_Image.frame.origin.x, view_Image.frame.origin.y, view_Image.frame.size.width, view_Image.frame.size.height)];

        [lblName setText:arrNames[i]];
        [view_Image addSubview:lblName];
        [mainScroll addSubview:view_Image];
    }
```

When i run the code, the UILabel appears on only the first UIImageView, for the rest the UIImageView appears on the top of the UILabel. (I found this by adding background color to the UILabel). How can i make the UILabel's appear on the UIImageView. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is the best way to go about putting a label on every `UIImageView`... subclassing would be a far neater approach.

Answer (score 1):

A view's frame is in it's superview's coordinate system. So each image view's frame is in `mainScroll`'s coordinate system.

Since each of your labels is a subview of a separate image view, each label's frame is in the coordinate system of its parent image view. But you are acting as though the label's frame is in the coordinates of `mainScroll`.

```
UILabel  *lblName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view_Image.bounds];
```